# Is there any way I can create a Scheduled Job with custom Job Name and Job Group for SFTP Endpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, sftp, quartz-scheduler

From URI of the Route looks like below

sftp://{{host}}/{{remoteFolderLocation}}?username={{username}}&password={{password}}&recursive=true&useUserKnownHostsFile=false
&move=.consumed&maximumReconnectAttempts=3&readLock=changed&readLockMinAge=10s&fastExistsCheck=true
**&scheduler=quartz2&scheduler.cron=0+0/10+*+1/1+*+?+***

I want to consume files from SFTP Server remote folder location and also have control on the Job Name and Job Group created by Camel Quartz2 Component

Can someone let me know how to achieve the above requirement??

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to use the `schedulerProperties` option in the endpoint uri. I don't how the syntax for it works, but to me it seems like that is the only way for naming the scheduler.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering, I'm using JDBC JobStore for avoiding Duplicate triggers when multiple instances of camel are up, The above From URI mentioned in the question creates the Job name with the UUID and the Job Group as Default, I want to control that part of the naming convention done by the QuartzScheduledPollConsumerScheduler actually the control I have is for Trigger ID and Trigger Group Naming but not on Job so I was checking on how to create a Job with custom name, Im not looking for Scheduler Name changes I'm good with Scheduler.

Comment: Then I have nothing to help you further. It may well be that what you are trying to achieve isn't supported by the sftp-component and you would need to use quartz for scheduling and read sftp separately.